# Ubuntu 21.04 screen share -- how to enable copy paste over vnc?

Tags: vnc, settings, 21.04, copy-and-paste

As stated in the title, Ubuntu 21.04 under sharing enables vnc and you can enable control as well. But copy/past is not working when connecting from another machine using RealVNC.

Is there a hidden setting to enable this? I been trying to find commands like vncconfig and things like that but they are not installed, I am assuming Ubuntu screen share uses some other software.

Share settings screen:

[image: share settings screenshot]

Share control panel screen:

[image: share-control-panel screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

From our understanding and research done it seems that Apple does not natively support the ability to copy/past & drag-drop between Mac and Ubuntu. A plausible workaround is to utilise RealVNC application.

Comment: Another good alternative is snapdrop.net works on the same network and cross all platform and device types - also free.